# Wattage Rating for these Zeners

Tags: audio, amplifier

I have a circuit ([Death of Zen audio amp](https://sound-au.com/project36.htm)) , which requires 2 12 volt zener diodes.
What is a safe wattage rating for them? [Does this work?](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/1N5242B-T/1N5242BDICT-ND/190605)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Further down the page on the [Death of Zen (DoZ) - A New Class-A Power Amp](https://sound-au.com/project36.htm) page there's a section on calculating the Zener power requirements:

> \$I_{z} = \frac{P_{z}} V_{z} \$ where \$I_{z}\$ is zener current, \$P_{z}\$ is the power rating, and \$V_{z}\$ is the zener voltage. 
>   Small zeners are typically rated at 400mW and 1W. A 33V 400mW zener therefore has a maximum current of 12mA. Allowing for a resistor voltage drop of 5 to 7 volts means that the zener current will be 5 to 7 mA (1V across 1k gives 1mA). Since it is recommended that zeners be operated at between 5% and 80% of the maximum rated current, this fits very nicely into our requirements.

Plugging in the numbers for your 500mW 12V Zener results in a maximum current of 42mA. That's around 15% of the current above and fits well within the 5 to 80% that Rod recommends so your selection is fine.

Those calculations are assuming an input voltage of around 30V, for the maximum 35V input you'd have an 11V (35V - 24V) drop across the resistor increasing the current to 11mA so your selection would still be OK.